# How to filter a Maybe value

Tags: haskell, monads, option-type

I am trying to create a function that validates an input `String -> Maybe Int`. I check to see if the input string is a number then check if that number is in a range. So far I have

```
validateNumber :: String -> Maybe Int
validateNumber n  = go $ (readMaybe::String -> Maybe Int) n
  where
    go (Just a) = inRange a
    go Nothing  = Nothing

inRange :: Int -> Maybe Int
inRange n
  | n > 0     = Just n
  | otherwise = Nothing
```

This feels like poor code. How should this be written?

Also, if I am trying to loop a function if it returns `Nothing`, what is the best way to do so:

So to loop the `main` function, I am doing :

```
case v of
  Nothing -> main
  Just x  -> {do something}
```

Comment: For the loop, you could use [`untilJust`](http://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=untilJust&scope=package%3Amonad-loops) from `monad-loops`

Comment: @4castle how would i actually write that. When I try to use `untilJust` I just get stuck on a loop on that line rather than have it loop back to the start of main so that I get all code prior to that line.

Comment: `x <- untilJust (validateNumber <$> getLine)` and you can replace `getLine` with an `IO String` that prompts for input first.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `mfilter` to filter out-of-range values within a `Maybe` instead of explicitly matching:

```
import Control.Monad (mfilter)

validateNumber :: String -> Maybe Int
validateNumber = mfilter (> 0) . readMaybe
```

Comment: that's really nice. Any comment on looping my function?

Comment: @matthias - What are the inputs to the function? Are you trying to find the first `Just` value in a list or is it the result of an `IO` action e.g. `IO (Maybe Int)`?

Comment: the input is a simple `getline` expecting a valid number. If the number is invalid, I want it to loop back and ask for the number again. If it is valid do something with it.

Comment: I would suggest asking your second question as a new question.

Comment: I find the type of `mfilter` odd. It seems like `MonadPlus m => (a -> Bool) -> a -> m a` would be much more natural. (I have found many uses for `ensure p x = x <$ guard (p x)`, which is essentially `mfilter` with my proposed relaxed type.) It wouldn't make this code significantly worse, either, since you could just use `(<=<)` in place of `(.)`.

Comment: @DanielWagner Probably `mfilter` is designed to just be a generalized version of `filter`.

Comment: @4castle I think `Witherable` is better generalization of `filter`.

Answer (score 8):

How about this?

```
validateNumber :: String -> Maybe Int
validateNumber n = (readMaybe n) >>= inRange
```

Or even this:

```
validateNumber :: String -> Maybe Int
validateNumber str = do
  n <- readMaybe str
  if n < 0 then Nothing else return n
```

(Avoids needing a separate `inRange` function.)

Comment: I think you could shorten the last line with `guard (n <0); return n`.

Comment: @epsilonhalbe You're suggesting that I "shorten" one line into two lines, which requires an additional import and is arguably less clear?

Comment: I am no fan of `if` but I guess that is a matter of taste. And you are right about the unnecessary import - I forgot that one!

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this (not tested):

```
validateNumber :: String -> Maybe Int
validateNumber n = case (readMaybe::String -> Maybe Int) n of
    (Just a) -> case n > 0 of
        True  -> Just n
        False -> Nothing
    Nothing  -> Nothing
```

It's a bit shorter and more concise.

Comment: i started out with nested cases but thought that that is something that we should be trying to avoid???

Comment: I wouldn't use the word "concise" to describe code that ignores the `Functor` instance of `Maybe`.

Comment: @chepner Maybe it was a bad choice of words.